# Enviar datos de una funcion a otra en varias clases

Tags: java

tengo un problema al hora de abrir una ventana desde otra usando una tercera como clase de todas las funciones, lo que trato es crear una funcion que reciba un numero entero, en un boton enviar este numero y que la funcion la reciba y posteriormente la envie a otra funcion de otra clase:

esta es la funcion que he hecho, la cual recibira el dato que el envie desde el boton y luego otra funcion lo recibira

```
public int regreso2(int numero){
    return numero;
    }
```

y este es el boton donde se enviara el dato

```
private void btnmostrarPAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    regreso2(1);
    
    mostrar_est mostrar = new mostrar_est();
    mostrar.setVisible(true);
    
}
```

finalmente esta es la funcion donde se recibira lo que envie regresar2, el problema es que siempre me recibe un cero, no se si estoy mal en la funcion regresar2

```
 public int mostrar(int numeros){
        principal nuevo = new principal();
    
        int num1 = nuevo.regreso2(numeros);
    
        System.out.println("numero retornado11 "+num1);
    
        if(num1==1)
        {
            return 1;
        
        }else if(num1==2 )
        {
            return 2;
        }
    
        return 0;      
    
}
```

Lo que necesito resolver es que al enviarle un dato a regresar2 desde el boton, este lo almacena y mostrar pueda recibirlo desde otra clase, el problema es que no lo hace, regresar2 si recibe el entero enviado desde el boton, pero no lo almacena para que *mostrar* que esta desde otra clase lo use, solo recibe 0.

Comment: Bienvenido. El código va como texto.

Comment: Hola. Para colocar varias líneas de código simplemente es copiar / pegar. Una vez pegado, selecciona todo el bloque y con él seleccionado pulsa en el símbolo **`{ }`** de la barra superior y todo ese bloque quedará como código. Por otra parte, parece que te faltó poner la última función, al final de la pregunta, cuando dices: *finalmente esta es la funcion donde se recibira lo que envie regresar2...*

Comment: De todos modos, es confuso todo. Por ejemplo, `regreso2()` no tiene sentido, porque devuelve lo mismo que le pasas. Tampoco se entiende el contexto. Es mejor que pongas toda la clase para ver el contexto y que luego en la redacción de la pregunta expliques la lógica y el problema que tienes. Eso de ir poniendo trozos de código para querer explicar una lógica quizá errónea no ayuda a entender el problema.

Comment: Esas son las 3 funciones, la primera es la de regresar2, la segunda es la del boton donde al presionarlo le envio el dato a regresar2 y la tercera es la funcion que recibe el parametro de regresar2, entonces lo que yo quiero es que en la funcion `mostrar(int numeros)`, se reciba el dato que se almacene en regresar2, **mostrar** esta en la clase 1 por ejemplo, y las otras 2 como **regresar** y el **boton** estan en una misma, el problema surge cuando presiono el boton y le pido que envie el dato a **regresar2**, lo hace, pero este envia un 0 a **mostrar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a desmenuzar tu código.

```
public int regreso2( int numero ) {
    return numero;
}
```

Piense en la función como si fuera una persona, tiene sentido darle a alguien 10 pesos para que te de 10 pesos?, por supuesto que no.

Veamos el botón **btnmostrarPA**.

```
private void btnmostrarPAActionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt ) {                                             
    regreso2( 1 );    
    mostrar_est mostrar = new mostrar_est();
    mostrar.setVisible( true );    
}
```

Cuando el botón es presionado, llamas a **regreso2** le pasas correctamente el parámetro, pero olvidas estirar la mano, independientemente de lo ya comentado, acerca del sin sentido de la función que devuelve lo que se le da, no se lo devuelve a nadie, osea, no hay una variable que almacene el valor devuelto por ella, debería ser algo como:

```
int valorGuardado = regreso2( 1 );
```

Es una forma de guardar un dato devuelto por una función.

Ahora vamos con el objetivo, pasar un valor desde una clase a otra.
Acá tenemos dos enfoques, que dependen de la estructura del programa.

A) desde la clase **Uno**, instanciamos un atributo de la clase **Dos**.

```
public class Uno {  
    int datoImportante = 1;  // el dato puede tener otro origen
    JButton btnmostrarPA = new JButton();  // obvio todo el código que ya tienes
    private void btnmostrarPAActionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt ) {  

           // creo un objeto de la clase Dos
        Dos claseDos = new Dos();

          // mediante el objeto invoco al método setDatoImportante()
        claseDos.setDatoImportante( datoImportante );

          // vuelvo a usar el objeto para invocar a hacerAlgoConElDato()
        claseDos.hacerAlgoConElDato();
    }  

public class Dos {
    int datoDeLaClaseUno;

    public void setDatoImportante( int dato ) {

          // instancio el atributo datoDeLaClaseUno
        datoDeLaClaseUno = dato;
    }

    public void hacerAlgoConElDato() {

          // uso datoDeLaClaseUno
        System.out.print( datoDeLaClaseUno );
    }    
}
```

B) desde la clase **Dos** le pedimos el dato a **Uno**.

```
public class Uno {  
    int datoImportante = 1;  // el dato puede tener otro origen

    public int getDatoDeLaClaseUno() {
        return datoImportante;
    }           
}  

public class Dos {

    public void hacerAlgoConElDato() {

          // creo un objeto de la clase Uno
        Uno claseUno = new Uno();

          // pido y uso datoDeLaClaseUno
        System.out.print( claseUno.getDatoDeLaClaseUno );
    }    
}
```